# Endomorphism ring of elliptic curves over $\Bbb Q$ vs over $\Bbb C$

Tags: elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb Q$. What is the relation between $End(E)$ and $End(E_{\Bbb C})$ ? 
We clearly have an inclusion
$End(E) \subset End(E_{\Bbb C})$ : given $f :E\to E$, we can base change it to get $f_{\Bbb C} : E_{\Bbb C} \to E_{\Bbb C}$. But is it possible to have a strict inclusion? Apparently I've seen that Chow proved
$End(E_{\overline{\Bbb Q}}) = End(E_{\Bbb C})$.

Of course, if $End(E_{\Bbb C}) = \Bbb Z$, then we have equality. But what if $E_{\Bbb C}$ has larger endomorphism ring?

Comment: If $E / L$ (L = number field) has CM by $K$, then $End_{\overline{\Bbb Q}}(E)  = End_{KL}(E)$, cf Silverman's AAEC chapter II... In general, we have $End_F(E) \subset F$, so $End_F(E) = \Bbb Z$ if F is totally real (cf https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14168/cm-of-elliptic-curves/14228#14228)

Comment: Yeah no idea what I meant, $End_F(E)\subset F$ follows from Lubin answer: (in $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ form) look at the invariant differential, it is sent to $\lambda dx/y$ with $\lambda\in F$ and $End_F(E)$ is (isomorphic to) the ring of such $\lambda$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elliptic curves with larger endomorphism rings than $\Bbb Z$ are said to have “complex multiplication”. Here are the most familiar two examples:
\begin{align}
y^2&=x^3+1\,,&\varphi(x,y)&=(\zeta_3x,y)\,,&(\zeta_3^2+\zeta_3+1&=0)\\
y^2&=x^3-x\,,&\varphi(x,y)&=(-x,iy)\,.
\end{align}

The elliptic curves with complex multiplication play a surprisingly large role in number theory. Others will point you to references, where you may read all about it.

**Edit** (addition)
In a word, the only endomorphisms not in $\Bbb Z$ are truly complex, in this sense: such an endomorphism $\varphi$ will satisfy an equation of type $\varphi^2+b\varphi + c=0$, with $b,c\in\Bbb Z$ and $b^2-4c<0$. And in particular, locally at the neutral point, the action on the tangent space is just that, $z\mapsto\lambda z$ with $\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$, same $b$ and $c$. In other words, the endomorphism itself can not have rational definition. Thus $\text{End}_{\Bbb Q}(E)=\Bbb Z$ always.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have $End(E)$ larger than $\Bbb Z$ ? In the examples you give, I think that these are endomorphisms over $\Bbb C$ but not over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Wow, I just discovered that $\text{End}_{\Bbb Q}(E)=\Bbb Z$ always! Thank you :-)

Comment: Just to be sure about the "tangent space" you mention at the end: is it the tangent space to $E( \Bbb C ) \cong \Bbb C / \Lambda$, or is it the Zariski tangent space to $E$ (over $\Bbb Q$)?

Comment: 2) Another question: in fact, we always have $End(E_{\Bbb R}) = \Bbb Z$, right?

Comment: To  your two questions: first, either tangent space will do. Second, yes, right.