# $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(E)=\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over the rational number field $\mathbb{Q}$, and I have seen $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(E)=\mathbb{Z}$ in many places ,but no proof is given. So I want to ask for a proof or a refernce!

Thanks

Comment: Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973865/endomorphism-ring-of-elliptic-curves-over-bbb-q-vs-over-bbb-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $E$ may have complex multiplication, so it has endomorphisms
over $\Bbb C$ which are outside $\Bbb Z$. But these are not defined over $\Bbb Q$.

To see this note that the endomorphism ring acts on the vector space of
invariant differentials on $E$ (spanned by $\omega=dx/(2y)$ for $y^2=x^3+ax+b$).
An endomorphism defined over $\Bbb Q$ takes $\omega$ to a rational
multiple of $\omega$, and so we get a ring map $\text{End}_{\Bbb Q}(E)\to
\Bbb Q$. No element of $\text{End}_{\Bbb C}(E)$ other that those in $\Bbb Z$
can map to and element of $\Bbb Q$ as in the CM case the endomorphism
ring in an order in an imaginary quadratic field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since $\text{char} (\mathbb{Q})=0$, $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(E)$ is isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}$ or is an order in an imaginary quadratic field $F$. We also have a map $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(E)\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, so this map extends to the fraction field of $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(E)$, so we have a ring homomorphism $F\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, which is obviously impossible, so $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(E) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, am I right?

Comment: @Eiang Yes, you are.

Comment: Sorry, one more time to disturb you, I want to know if there exists some nonzero element in $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(E)$ such that it takes $omega$ to $0$(because if there is no such an element, then the map can be extended to the fraction field).

Comment: If $R$ is an order in an imaginary quadratic field, then any non-trivial quotient ring of $R$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, I see. And I also have another proof for this, assume there is a complex number $t$ in the order, then $t$ satisfies a quadratic equation with integer coefficients of discriminant less than 0, assume the map which you give takes $t$ to $s\in \mathbb{Q}$, than $s$ must also satisfy this equation by the additive group homomorphism, which is obviously impossible.