# Elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ have no complex multiplication

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Then how can I show that $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb{Q}(E) \cong \mathbb{Z}$?
I know that $\operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{Q}(E) = \{ \pm 1\}$ and that $\operatorname{End}$ is either $\mathbb{Z}$ or an order of an imaginary quadratic field.

This is related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112343/irreduciblity-of-ell-adic-representation-attach-to-the-elliptic-curve-over).

Comment: On the complex torus side the pullback $\omega \mapsto f^*\omega=c_f\omega$ is quite obvious (it is $dz \mapsto c_f dz$ where the endomorphism is $z+\Lambda\to c_f z+\Lambda$ with $c_f \Lambda \subset \Lambda$), you need to clarify that it works on the algebraic curve side too

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973865/endomorphism-ring-of-elliptic-curves-over-bbb-q-vs-over-bbb-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elliptic curve
$$E:\qquad y^2=x^3+Ax+B$$
has an invariant differential
$$\omega=\frac{dx}{2y}=\frac{dy}{3x^2+A}$$
which is characterised up to scalar multiplication that it
has no zeros or poles.
Given an endomorphism
$$f:E\to E$$
the pullback $f^*\omega$ is a multiple of $\omega$:
$$f^*\omega=c_f\omega.$$
Now $f\mapsto c_f$ is a ring homomorphism; it preserves addition and
takes composition to composition.

Now if $E$ and $f$ are defined over $\Bbb Q$ then $c_f\in\Bbb Q$.
So $f\mapsto c_f$ is a homomorphism from $\text{End}_{\Bbb Q}(E)$
to $\Bbb Q$ which is impossible if $\text{End}_{\Bbb Q}(E)$ contains
an element outside $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much!